# Retain position in List Fragment after changing the cursor in Android

Tags: android

I'm using an SQLiteCursorLoader by extending AsyncTaskLoader with list fragment, I managed to retain the position when new data comes in by saving the position and the view, and then use setSelectionFromTop(), that was working perfectly fine.

This is how it's currently working,

DB data before cursor reload,

```
Field1 int, timestamp long
------------------
First row, now  
Second row, 1 minute ago
Third row, 2 minutes ago  -----> user is currently on this item in the listview
```

DB after cursor reload,

```
Field1 int, timestamp long
------------------
Fourth row, now
First row, 30 secon ago
Second row, 1 minute + 30 seconds ago
Third row, 2 minutes + 30 seconds ago --> go here using setSelectionFromTop(position, y)
```

After the cursor reloads, I retain the position of the "Third row" as I save the old position, 
so all I needed to do is to calculate the old position - the new cursor count

Now I have a new requirements (shown below) where not only new data will come in, but also old data will change which will mess up the positions, what will change is the time stamp of the old data, so the result of the query used in the SQLiteCursorLoader will be different, I can no longer use the old method.

```
Field1 int, timestamp long
------------------
First row, now  
Second row, 1 minute ago
Third row, 2 minutes ago  -----> user is currently on this item in the listview
```

DB after cursor reload,

```
Field1 int, timestamp long
------------------
Third row, now
First row, 30 secon ago
Second row, 1 minute + 30 seconds ago
```

As you can see the position won't be the same now. Now I have to use getItemId to get the DB id and save it and when the cursor reload I will have to go through it to get it's position.

My question is, is it possible to do it in another/faster way?

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

solution  for this to selectively block ListView laying out it’s children. why it is not retaining it's position is ListView laying out it’s children to display the new items at the old position. If we stop the children layout pass, we stop the visible change in position.

Make a cutom Listview Widget like this:

```
public class BlockingListView extends ListView {

    private boolean mBlockLayoutChildren;

    public BlockingListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setBlockLayoutChildren(boolean block) {
        mBlockLayoutChildren = block;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        if (!mBlockLayoutChildren) {
            super.layoutChildren();
        }
    }
}
```

And use this new widget like this..

```
int firstVisPos = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View firstVisView = mListView.getChildAt(0);
int top = firstVisView != null ? firstVisView.getTop() : 0;

// Block children layout for now 
mListView.setBlockLayoutChildren(true);

// Number of items added before the first visible item 
int itemsAddedBeforeFirstVisible = ...;

// Change the cursor, or call notifyDataSetChanged() if not using a Cursor
mAdapter.swapCursor(...);

// Let ListView start laying out children again 
mListView.setBlockLayoutChildren(false);

// Call setSelectionFromTop to change the ListView position
mListView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisPos + itemsAddedBeforeFirstVisible, top);
```